Why Is Range Worksheet's Object Failing?
I'm trying to change the value of the cell "L83", as another cell is updated manually. those cells make part of a table.
this is the code that I'm using:
    Sub UpdateCell()
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("$L$83").Value = "AAA"
        Sheets(1).Range("L83").Value = "AAA"
        Sheets(1).Cells(83, 12).Value = "AAA"
        Sheets(1).ListObjects("tblLIBERACOES").DataBodyRange(83, 12).Value = "AAA"
    End Sub

all of those 3 options raise the following error:

Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)'
Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed

I'm using Excel 365.
thanks in advance.
P.S: Here goes my full code:
Change event:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    UpdateALERTS Target
End Sub

UpdateALERTS procedure:
Sub UpdateALERTS(fieldNAME As Range)
    If (IsInsideColumn("REGISTRATION DATE")) Then
        EraseALERTS fieldNAME
    End If
End Sub

IsInsideColumn procedure:
Function IsInsideColumn(columnName As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    
    Dim tRng As Range
    
    Set tRng = Intersect(Sheets(1).ListObjects("tblLIBERACOES").ListColumns(columnName).Range, ActiveCell)
    
    If Not tRng Is Nothing Then IsInsideColumn = True
    
    Set tRng = Nothing
End Function

EraseALERTS procedure:
Sub EraseALERTS(fieldNAME As Range)
    Dim colYELLOW As Integer
    Dim line As Integer
    
    colYELLOW = Sheets(1).ListObjects("tblLIBERACOES").ListColumns("YELLOW ALERT").Range.Column
    line = fieldNAME.Row
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Sheets(1).Cells(line, colYELLOW).Value = ""
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub


Maybe Sheets(1) is not a worksheet?  If you know you want a worksheet then it's typically better to work with the Worksheets collection, since Sheets also contains other types of sheet, such as Chart sheets.

^^^ see here

@TimWilliams yes, it is. when I print Sheets(1).Name it returns the name of the sheet properly.

Yes I just tested and the non-worksheet-related error would be Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method.

When you get the error is there a "Debug" button?  Do you have any event handlers on the sheet you're updating?

@TimWilliams I executed the code step-by-step and figured that when I do the change in the cell with UpdateCell procedure, it goes to the Worksheet_Change event and runs whatever is there. I removed the code from Worksheet_Change event and it worked fine. what happens is that I've got to put the UpdateCell code into Worksheet_Change event. basically, I need to delete a cell B content, as I change cell A date. if I edit or delete the date, I need to clear cell B.

Might be useful to include your event code here if you need help with that.

you guys helped me a lot! it is working now. I'll paste my code here so other guys can make a good use of it. I still can't simulate Before_Change event in Excel. my idea was to do the change in cell B just if the date was really changed to a different one or if it was deleted.

@TimWilliams the problem is that inside Worksheet_Change event I run a code that does change to cell B which triggers Worksheet_Change event again. it stops Excel.

You can use Application.Undo  inside the change event handler, if you want to check what the previous cell value was.

...and use Application.EnableEvents = False if you're updating a cell and don't want the event handler to fire.  Don't forget to set it back to True when you're done.

@TimWilliams that's exactly what I did. I used Application.EnableEvents = False before the cell change. right after I set EnableEvents back to True. now, I'll try Application.Undo, as you said.

Since you are working with Worksheet_Change event, you may want to see This

A Worksheet Change: Change Value in the Corresponding Row of Another Column in an Excel Table

I'm not sure how convenient it is to split this into so many procedures. I would use the following instead.
The code will only run when a single cell is changed.

Sheet Module, e.g. Sheet1
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    EraseAlert Target
End Sub

Standard Module, e.g. Module1, or the Same Sheet Module
Sub EraseAlert(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim WasSuccess As Boolean: WasSuccess = True
    Dim MsgString As String
    On Error GoTo ClearError ' start error-handling routine
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const TABLE_NAME As String = "tblLIBERACOES"
    Const TARGET_COLUMN_TITLE As String = "REGISTRATION DATE"
    Const CHANGE_COLUMN_TITLE As String = "YELLOW ALERT"
    Const CHANGE_VALUE As String = vbNullString
    
    ' Restrict 'Target' to a single cell.
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Reference the ranges.
    Dim targetColumn As Range, changeColumn As Range, targetCell As Range
    With Target.Worksheet.ListObjects(TABLE_NAME)
        Set targetColumn = .ListColumns(TARGET_COLUMN_TITLE).DataBodyRange
        Set targetCell = Intersect(targetColumn, Target)
        If targetCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' not in target column
        Set changeColumn = .ListColumns(CHANGE_COLUMN_TITLE).DataBodyRange
    End With
    
    ' Store the changed value in a variable.
    Dim TargetValue As Variant: TargetValue = targetCell.Value
    
    ' Disable events to prevent retriggering this or triggering any other event
    ' (all or nothing).
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    ' Undo to check if there was a change or the user changed his/her mind...
    Application.Undo ' selects the cell
    Application.Goto targetCell.Offset(1) ' therefore, select the one below
    
    ' ... i.e. just confirmed (pressed 'Enter') the same value:
    If CStr(targetCell.Value) <> CStr(TargetValue) Then
        ' Write back the changed value.
        targetCell.Value = TargetValue
        ' Change the value in the change column.
        Intersect(targetCell.EntireRow, changeColumn).Value = CHANGE_VALUE
    'Else ' no change; do nothing
    End If

ProcExit:
    On Error Resume Next ' defer error trapping; prevent endless loop
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        If Not WasSuccess Then MsgBox MsgString, vbCritical
    On Error GoTo 0 ' enable error trapping
    Exit Sub
ClearError: ' continue error-handling routine
    MsgString = "Run-time error [" & Err.Number & "]:" _
        & vbLf & vbLf & Err.Description
    WasSuccess = False
    Resume ProcExit ' redirect error-handling routine
End Sub


I split it in some procedures because I use them for reasons of code reusability.
